# Not able to Returning an Anonymous type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have following function with **returning Anonymous type**.

```
public IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> GetJsonTabMasterList(string OrderByColumn, string OrderType, int PageSize, int CurrentPage)
        {
            IQueryable<TabMaster> tabmasters = _tabmasterRepository.GetQueryable().OrderUsingSortExpression(OrderByColumn + " " + OrderType).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = 1,//totalPages,
                page = 1,//page,
                records = 14, //totalRecords,
                rows = (from tm in tabmasters
                        select new
                        {
                            id = tm.colID,
                            cell = new string[] { tm.colID.ToString(), tm.FirstName, tm.LastName }
                        }).ToArray()
            };
            return jsonData;
        }
```

but it will gives me an following **Error**:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 
'System.Linq.IQueryable'

I have confusion for define return type function in following line

```
public IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> ...
```

Comment: change your return type to `object`.

Comment: **but now i am getting new error:** LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. at following line cell = new string[] { tm.colID.ToString(), tm.FirstName, tm.LastName }

Comment: First you have to check whether your LINQ query works properly. Try replacing `tm.colID.ToString()` with `tm.colID`.

Comment: yes my LINQ query works properly. and  i am updated code for tm.colID. but still issue persist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are solution:

```
public JsonResult GetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int rows, int page)
        {
            int totalRecords = Convert.ToInt32(_tabmasterService.Count());
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
            IQueryable<TabMasterViewModel> tabmasters = _tabmasterService.GetQueryTabMasterList(sidx, sord, rows, page);
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (from tm in tabmasters
                        select new
                        {
                            id = tm.colID,
                            cell = new string[] { tm.colID.ToString(), tm.FirstName, tm.LastName }
                        }).ToArray()
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want some sort of type here, you can create a class or structure called

```
public class TabMasterDataInfo
{
 public int Total {get;set;}
 public int Page {get;set;}
 public int Records {get;set;}
 public IEnumerable Rows {get;set;}
}
```

and then

```
 var jsonData = new TabMasterDataInfo()
            {
                Total = 1,//totalPages,
                Page = 1,//page,
                Records = 14, //totalRecords,
                Rows = (from tm in tabmasters
                        select new
                        {
                            id = tm.colID,
                            cell = new string[] { tm.colID.ToString(), tm.FirstName, tm.LastName }
                        }).ToArray()
            };
```

and your method returns then type TabMasterDataInfo

```
public TabMasterDataInfo GetJsonTabMasterList(string OrderByColumn, string OrderType, int PageSize, int CurrentPage)
```

This is the rough idea anyways.. assuming you want a type return (which I would far prefer to 'object' -there is no guessing then and its strongly typed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. and i updated code according to yours but still issue persist with following error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Use Convert.ToString(tm.colID) instead tm.colID.ToString().
Linq doesn't like .ToString() there.

Comment: What happens when you use my solution?